# cakephp turn postLink into button

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I want to change the delete postLink into a button. I have tried many combinations but changing to button makes the form submit and not redirect to the delete method.

Not sure what is left that I could try.

```
<?= $this->Form->postButton(__('X', ['type' => 'button']), ['controller' => 'StrategiesConditions', 'action' => 'delete', $strategiesConditions['id']], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $strategiesConditions['id'])]) ?>
```

Overall code

```
    <div class="strategies form content">
        <?= $this->Form->create($strategy) ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?= __('Edit Strategy') ?></legend>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
                echo $this->Form->control('name');
                echo $this->Form->control('description');
                echo $this->Form->control('one_hundred_trades');
            ?>
            <table id="conditions-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Level</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="condtitions-input"></input>
                            <select id="condtitions-level">
                                <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
                                <option value="Important">Important</option>
                                <option value="Support">Support</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="add-condtition" type='button' onclick="addCondition()">Add Conditions</button></td>
                        </td>  
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($strategy->strategies_conditions as $key=>$strategiesConditions) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('strategies_conditions.' . $key . '.id'); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->control('strategies_conditions.'.$key.'.name', array( 'label' => false )); ?>
                            <select name="strategies_conditions[<?=$key?>][level]">
                                <option <?= ($strategiesConditions['level'] == "Mandatory") ? 'selected="selected"' : "" ?> value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
                                <option <?= ($strategiesConditions['level'] == "Important") ? 'selected="selected"' : ""  ?> value="Important">Important</option>
                                <option <?= ($strategiesConditions['level'] == "Support") ? 'selected="selected"' : ""  ?> value="Support">Support</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('X', ['type' => 'button']), ['controller' => 'StrategiesConditions', 'action' => 'delete', $strategiesConditions['id']], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $strategiesConditions['id'])]) ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>                       
                </thead>
            </table>                
        </fieldset>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want to change what it looks like, or how it behaves?

Comment: I want to change the look from just text to a button but still have the behaviour of deleting the associated record. Just like in the view.php

Comment: actually I noticed that using `postLink` creates a form. For some reason the `foreach` loop only creates the `<form >` around the last delete link and so only the last record can be deleted. When I click the records above noting happens

Comment: Just noticed that this is your edit page, so the whole thing is wrapped inside of a form. While there are ways to do that with HTML5, this will not be generating that sort of code. What you'll be getting here is invalid HTML, and results are therefore unpredictable; you might get different behaviour from different browsers. Anyway, wouldn't delete links from here send you to a different page, thus losing any edits you'd made? What you probably need here is either some sort of Ajax link or else a "delete this" checkbox that your controller handles.

Comment: In addition to what Greg Schmidt says: you cannot place your postlink between `$this->Form->create()` and `$this->Form->end()`.

Comment: What's the issue? [This demo](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/bootstrap/post-link) shows how easy it is to add CSS classes which makes it appear as button.

Comment: unfortunatly I cannot style a `postLink` to look like a button because it is sitting in a form already. Is there a way to have a button that post the `id` to the delete method without using a `form`

Answer (score 0):

I have used Cakephp `block` to solve the `form` with `form` issue and I added style to make like a button.

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('X'), 
       [
          'controller' => 'StrategiesConditions', 
          'action' => 'delete', 
           $strategiesConditions->id
       ], 
       [
           'block' => true,
           'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
           'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $strategiesConditions['id'])
           ]) ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>                       
                </thead>
            </table>                
        </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
<?=  $this->fetch('postLink'); ?>
```

Comment: Jep, that is documented: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-post-links

Comment: Pays to look at the docs alright, I was never good with reading manuals :-)